# REST API PATCH - update a specific value in an object

Tags: rest, http

In a config file, I've got several vars.

```
{
    "key1": "aaa",
    "key2": {"smallkey1": "bbb", "smallkey2": "ccc"} 
}
```

---

I need to update `smallkey2` value, through a `patch` request (API obligation).

```
const updateConfigVar = (finaltarget, newdata) => {
    HTTP.call( 'PATCH', 'https://api.xxx.com/apps/', {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        data: {
            [finaltarget]: newdata,
        }
    })
}
```

---

If I call `updateConfigVar('key2', 'ddd')`, I get:

```
{
    "key1": "aaa",
    "key2": "ddd" 
}
```

---

**But how to replace not the all `key2` object but only the value of `smallkey2` inside the `key2` object.**

So how to get:

```
{
    "key1": "aaa",
    "key2": {"smallkey1": "bbb", "smallkey2": "ddd"} 
}
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? How is it supposed to know you want to target smallkey2?

Comment: First, `PATCH` is actually an operation where the client should calculate the necessary steps a server should apply in order to transform the state of the resource to fit the clients needs. The request should therefore contain a set of instructions the server should apply atomically (either all or none of them are applied). Second, it depends on what media-type you are using. I.e. a [`application/json-patch+json`](http://jsonpatch.com/) should be rather self explanatory while [`application/merge-patch+json`](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7386) has totally different semantics

Answer (score 0):

> But how to replace not the all key2 object but only the value of smallkey2 inside the key2 object.

Normally, if we are using [HTTP Patch](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) to communicate a change to the server

> The set of changes is represented in a format called a "patch document" identified by a media type.

You probably don't want to be using `application/json` as your media type, because the processing rules for JSON aren't specific to patching.  A better bet would be to use either `application/json-patch+json` (described by [RFC 6902](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902)) or `application/merge-patch+json` (described by [RFC 7386](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7386)).

Each of these has their own specific semantics for describing an edit to a nested key.